# Using general odd-even specifications in beamer overlay

Tags: beamer, overlays

Please consider the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Odd-Even Overlay}

  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<1,3>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Now in the odd ones.
    \end{itemize}

    \onslide<2,4>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Now in the even ones.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{overprint}

  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 1
    \end{itemize}

    \onslide<+>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 2
    \end{itemize}

    \onslide<+>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 3
    \end{itemize}

    \onslide<+>
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 4
    \end{itemize}
  \end{overprint}
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now, instead of writing `\onslide<1,3>` or `\onslide<2,4>` in the top overlay, I want to write something like `\onslide<odd-ones-only>` or `\onslide<even-ones-only>`.

How can I do that?